# TFS notification doesnt work for kanban board column changes

Tags: tfs, notifications

TFS 2018 update 2

I added a column "PO Review" to the kanban board.

then I added a notification as follows:
 "board column" "changes to" "PO Review"
but I never get notification.

However, when I defined notification as follows:
 "board column" "changes to" "Done"
I get the notification

it seems only the notifications over board column changes that cause a state change are working.
[image: screenshot]
any suggestion?

Comment: Can you share your notification definition?

Comment: Did your notifications in other area such as build, release, work item works well?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT yes it works in other areas.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk see the picture here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/313056/tfs-notification-doesnt-work-for-kanban-board-colu.html

Comment: Do you see any errors on the Event Viewer? (in the App Tier)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

for more details see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/313056/tfs-notification-doesnt-work-for-kanban-board-colu.html

the root cause was https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365527/board-column-field-shows-the-wrong-value.html